# python selenium add value to attribute named value

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to add with python selenium framework, to input tag's `value` attribute equals let's say `New York, NY`. I guess I need for it, like `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",element, value)` but do not know how to use it. Any kind of support will be appreciated

```
<input type="text" role="combobox" aria-owns="react-autowhatever-1" aria-expanded="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" class="StyledFormControl-c11n-8-82-0__sc-18qgis1-0 jxPUpE Input-c11n-8-82-0__sc-4ry0fw-0 qODeK react-autosuggest__input" placeholder="Enter an address, neighborhood, city, or ZIP code" aria-label="Search: Suggestions appear below" id="search-box-input" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to this code block

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",element, value)
```

Where **element** is the `input` element.

```
element=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search-box-input")
```

**value** is the text you would like to set here.

```
value='New York, NY'
```

So you can write in a single line

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search-box-input"), 'New York, NY')
```

Comment: is it similar to `element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "search-box-input")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','New York,NY')", element)
`